# Can't run Maven for Hadoop project inside IDE but it does get compiled Outside of IDE

Tags: hadoop, intellij-idea, maven-3

I downloaded and installed:

- -Maven
- -Cloudera Hadoop
- -IntelliJ IDEA ultimate
- -Tom Whites' hadoop source examples from his GitHub: https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/

When I open the POM.xml inside IntelliJ and do a Maven Compile or Maven Package, it fails with error like this:

```
2,27] package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist                   
3,27] package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist                   
4,27] package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist                   
5,34] package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist            
6,44] package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input does not exist  
7,45] package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output does not exist 
:[6,27] package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist                 
:[7,27] package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist                 
:[8,31] package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist             
:[9,31] package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
```

and also many symbol not found errors like this:

```
[ERROR] /Users/me/Downloads/hadoop-book-master/ch02/src/main/java/oldapi/MaxTemperatureReducer.java:[14,13] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Reducer
  implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
[ERROR] /Users/me/Downloads/hadoop-book-master/ch02/src/main/java/oldapi/MaxTemperatureReducer.java:[14,21] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Text
  implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
[ERROR] /Users/me/Downloads/hadoop-book-master/ch02/src/main/java/oldapi/MaxTemperatureReducer.java:[14,27] cannot find symbol
```

BUT If I go to command line and copy paste the command he has said in the readme of his github, Maven Package gets done successfully.

```
Then you can build the code with:

% mvn package -DskipTests -Dhadoop.version=1.1.1

(Note that only the Hadoop version numbers specified in hadoop-meta/pom.xml
can be used here, not any version of Hadoop.)
```

Comment: The Hadoop libs aren't in your `CLASSPATH`. No idea 'bout IDEA (oh the irony), but you gotta look for something like "configure build path" or "project classpath" and add the Hadoop jars to it (Maven fetches them into `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/` by default, if you compiled it they should be present). Or try looking for the possibility to import a Maven project, if IDEA isn't completely incompetent, there should be an option for that. Or just use Eclipse.